# Android-webview inside cardview, no rounded corners on lollipop

Tags: android, webview, material-design, android-cardview

in order to show a webview with round corners, I've put that inside a CardView and the result is as expected, a webview with round corners.

but when testing the app on `lollipop` the corners are not rounded, only a simple webview is shown. how to fix it on `lollipop`?

update: the code is mentioned below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#222222"
android:clickable="true">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="30dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/top_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:cardElevation="10dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/page_address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_edge">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/address_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="2dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/top_bar"
            android:scrollbars="none" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Add your current source code that not working yet.

Comment: what is your target sdk and minsdk in app.gradle

Comment: @sashabeliy min:21 target:29

Answer (score 0):

in your app.gradle change like this

```
compileSdkVersion 29
minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
```

and sync project

Comment: I don't understand what is the point of this answer, the min sdk version is 21 in my app, why should I change it to 15?!

Comment: because I had the same problem with corner radius when I had min sdk version 21 in my app with lollipop device after changing to 15 it solved my issue

Comment: I cannot change the minSdkVersion to 15 because of other libraries

Comment: post your java code then you have to use lolipop annotation in java code it will help I think